# how to create button programmatically and placing on my image in a root vie controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

i have an image in place of tab bar in my rootview controller of navigation controller....
i want to show buttons on to my image at bottom of my view ...

thanks in advance for suggestions also....

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, drag in a new `UIButton`. Change its Type to “Custom.” Change its Image to the image you’d like to display. Set its size, location, autoresize springs & struts, and outlets as necessary.